# Switching to 144Hz refresh rate is causing a flickering and half of the screen gone

Tags: display, resolution

I have a acer nitro 5 AN515-55 with I5-10th gen internal and 1660GTX card. When i increase the refresh rate of my laptop display to 144Hz from advance display menu, display flickers and half of my screen is black. but when i change it back to 60Hz laptop screen works fine. How can i fix this.

- Screen resolution is 1080P and 144Hz is supported by the display
- OS is windows 11 build 22H3
- Drivers are up-to date (intel and Nvidia)

Comment: is that a legal display mode ofr that display?

Comment: @Jasen It is, according to the specifications: *39,6 cm (15,6") Full HD (1920 x 1080) 16:9 IPS 144Hz*

Comment: What are the resolution and quality settings?

Comment: Which OS? Are the graphics drivers installed?

Comment: I have seen similar issues reported by other manufacturers like Asus too. Is it a known issue in high refresh rate panels?